# The custom shortcut I created does not work, what could be the reason?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm creating a custom shortcut in SSMS. For this, I follow these steps:

Tools → Environment → Keyboard → Query Shortcuts

For example, for ctrl + 3, I write select * from and say ok. But this shortcut doesn't work on my query window.

Why could this be?

Answer (score 5):

Restart of SSMS is not necessary.

The Query Shortcuts [Ctrl+3], will not work on the same query page(session).

Please, Try with New Query(Ctrl+N), and Try your Shortcut it will work now.

Answer (score 3):

Query shortcut changes do not start working immediately, they require a restart of SSMS after making the change.